# How can we pass table and schema name as parametrized sql query from c#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to pass parameterized schema, table name with some other parameterized values.

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"Insert INTO [dbo].[UserTypes][@Schema].[@Table] ([Name],[Description]) VALUES(@NAME, @Description)",
                                         new SqlParameter("@Schema", "dbo"),
                                         new SqlParameter("@Table", "UserTypes"),
                                         new SqlParameter("NAME", "AA"),
                                         new SqlParameter("Description", "Test"));
```

Comment: No you can't...

Comment: @mjwills do you have any other approach to solve the issue.

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=parametrize%20table%20name%20sql&qs=n&sk=&sc=1-26&form=BDKTKB&pc=BDT1&shash=&BDParam=0000&mkt=en-US

Comment: in the specific example, the table-name and schema-name are always fixed *anyway*, so... there's nothing to do? just use `[dbo].[UserTypes]`

Comment: Yes but in our case we have custom tables with schema created by users in our application.

Comment: "we have custom tables with schema created by users in our application." - that won't end well!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot parameterize the object identity, schema, column, etc; you'd need to use string concatenation for *those* parts - just parameterizeing the *values*. For example:

```cs
string schema = ..., table = ..., name = ..., description = ...;
// TODO: check schema and table are in an expected/allow-list, to prevent SQL injection
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($@"Insert INTO [{schema}].[{table}] ([Name],[Description]) VALUES(@NAME, @Description)",
         new SqlParameter("NAME", name),
         new SqlParameter("Description", description));
```

Comment: Thanks, but my existing code is already like you are suggesting but the Veracode code analysis tool found it SQL injected so what should be the solution to resolve the flaw.

Comment: @user3747994 see the "TODO" line, and when you've done that: mark that as a false-positive (because: you've now handled it) in the Veracode tool. It was correct to flag it - without that "TODO" line it is a risk, but: once you've dealt with that: you're done

Comment: @user3747994 in the case where the schema and table names are supplied by users, creating an allow-list is a *little* more difficult - you may need to run some queries on `sys.schemas` and `sys.tables` - and even then, there are edge cases: for example a table can be called `a]b`, which means you need to *escape* it; honestly, if it was me: I'd enforce that your user-generated schemas and table names are *only* allowed with ASCII alpha-numerics plus underscores, but *especially* don't allow `]` or `[` - and your validity check can then just enforce that via a regex